# How to know if a Google Geocoding API response is a house, a building or none of them, specifically for Santiago de Chile, Chile (City, Country)?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

For the Google Geocoding API (any version), is there any way to know if the response location (coordinate - latitude and longitude) is refereed to a 'house', a 'building' or none of them?

The idea here is to 'categorize' the location.

Given a list of human readable addresses (street name, number, zip, etc) I need to categorize each one of them as 'House', 'Building' or 'None'.

Request example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Dieciocho%2045%2C%20Santiago%2C%20Region%20Metropolitana&key={{key}}&components=country:CL
```

With the example the "location_type" is "ROOFTOP" (perfect accuracy) but even thou I don't see any address_component that can give me the information I need. Am I missing something?

I have read the api documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses) but didn't find anything helpful for the case.

Does anyone know how to achieve this result?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way in the Geocoding API (and Places API) to tell whether a result is known (to Google Maps) to be a building of some sort or not.

In your example, `"types" : [ "street_address" ]` indicates the address is not tied to a specific building, in the API. There may actually be a building at that location in real life, it's just that the API does not know about it. So this is kinda telling you "don't know".

In the following example, `"types" : [ "premise" ]` the result indicates this is some kind of building... but as you can see, it's actually a cathedral:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-29.903018,-71.251052

For more fine grain distinctions, [Places API Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) lets you search for pretty much everything Google Maps does, and shows [more types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types). These don't seem like they'll be enough to tell residential houses from other buildings though, may want to [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request) for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems to be the feature I was looking does not exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

For such a purpose, use Google Places API.

From JS v3 API, snippet is like this:

```
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(...),
    radius: 10,
    type: ['store']
  }, callback);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

Comment: But it's not a 'store' what I need to figure out if the location is about. I need to know if whether is a residential house, a building or something different than those 2 options. I haven't found such options yet.

Comment: I just show you that you can use nearBySearch() method for your purpose. 'store' is a just example. Please read the document by yourself.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

If this is not your answer, Google does not have api for your purpose.

Comment: While Google may not now have what you need, I think this answer was quite far from what the original question aimed for. At least I understood at first OP was asking for a way to tell whether any given result was a building or house, not for a way to find specific types of buildings in specific locations (which is what NearbySearch does do well).